# how to get a console shell on my symbian phone?

Tags: shell, symbian, s60

How do I get a bash or a similar shell for my new Symbian s60 rev 5 phone (Nokia 5800) ?

I already installed putty for s60, but it does not have telnet and it seems that there is no local ssh server running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- There's [**eshell**](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Eshell_on_S60_5th_edition_SDK) but it is usually not included in phone SW that is put on the device. You can use it on emulator though.
- There's a port of [**zsh**](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/A_Guide_To_P.I.P.S.#Zsh_and_Telnet_daemon) that you can also run on the device. It's way more powerful than eshell.

Comment: Oops, the zsh link is pointing to a site that is down. Any alternatives?

Comment: symbian.com is being migrated over to symbian.org and the zsh related stuff on symbian.org is now behind a Symbian Foundation membership login :( I'll send the SF people some feedback that content that used to be freely available is no longer so.

Comment: Got a response from SF technical comms team and they've put up the downloads on an updated page. I updated my answer to point to the new location.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://twmdesign.co.uk/theblog/?p=98) is an article which explains text console in Carbide. You just should add `-dtextshell` parameter. It will work for emulator, but I'm not sure if it works on the device.

Comment: This will only work on the emulator.  It tells the system to use a text-only UI, rather than the default full GUI.  Once booted, the text-only UI will present the user with an eshell prompt.
As laalto commented, eshell is also available from a GUI environment, though it typically isn't installed on the device.

Comment: Thank you for the link, which is great!